# Foreach loop only save last array values but the var_dump show different results

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to save last array from a loop using foreach

Based on the logic for each $keyword as long the $threadcount not meet $maxthread it will setup all variables needed and then call $google->getBrowser then saving the array variables from $google->getBrowser into $bparr

The variable $bparr[$keyword] only showing the last array variables from $google->getBrowser() but var_dump($google->getBrowser) showing it right

How to add each $google->getBrowser results into $bparr and not only the last results ?

```
if ($multi)
{
    $threadcount = 0;
    $e = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $page = 1;
    $proxy = array();
    $browser = array();
    $uafilearr = array();
    $cfarr = array();
    $browser = $google->getBrowser();
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        // setup browser option as array
        if($threadcount < $maxthreads)
        {
            if (!empty($pfile))
            {
                $proxy[$keyword] = proxySetup($pfile);
                // explode the proxy to find out if there is username and password
                // usually there is 4 array_count if there is username and password
                $exproxy = explode(":", $proxy[$keyword]);
            
                if (count($exproxy) == 2)
                {
                    $proxyip = $exproxy[0].":".$exproxy[1];
                    $browser->setProxy($proxyip);
                    $browser->setProxyAuth('');
                }
    
                if (count($exproxy) == 4)
                {
                    $proxyip = $exproxy[0].":".$exproxy[1];
                    $proxyauth = $exproxy[2].":".$exproxy[3];
                    $browser->setProxy($proxyip);
                    $browser->setProxyAuth($proxyauth);
                }
            }
            if (!empty($cookiesdir))
            {
                clearstatcache();
                $uafile = $cookiesdir.'\gtu-'.md5($proxy[$keyword]).'.txt';
                $uafilearr[$keyword] = $uafile;
                if (file_exists($uafile)) {
                    $useragent = file_get_contents($uafile);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    touch($uafile);
                    if (!empty($agentfile))
                    {
                        $useragent = agent($agentfile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // you can change the useragent defined here
                        $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36";
                    }
                    file_put_contents($uafile, $useragent);

                }
                $browser->setUserAgent($useragent);
        
                $cookiesfile = $cookiesdir.'\gtc-'.md5($proxy[$keyword]).'.txt';
                $cfarr[$keyword] = $cookiesfile;
                if (!file_exists($cookiesfile)) {               
                    touch($cookiesfile);
                }
                $browser->setCookieFile($cookiesfile);
            }
            var_dump($google->getBrowser());
            if( !isset($bparr[$keyword])) $bparr[$keyword] = array();
            $bparr[$keyword] = $google->getBrowser();
        }
        else
        {
            break 1;
        }
        $threadcount++;
        
    }
    echo "proxy array\n";
    var_dump($proxy);
    echo "\n";
    echo "useragent array\n";
    var_dump($uafilearr);
    echo "\n";
    echo "cookies array\n";
    var_dump($cfarr);
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "browser array\n";
    var_dump($bparr);
    echo "\n";
}
```

below is the results of var_dump($google->getBrowser());

```
object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signe
d-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
    string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    ["Accept-Charset"]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
    ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["Keep-Alive"]=>
    string(3) "115"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(90) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    [10102]=>
    string(0) ""
    [81]=>
    int(0)
    [64]=>
    int(0)
    [58]=>
    int(1)
    [78]=>
    int(10)
    [13]=>
    int(15)
    [10065]=>
    string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
    [10097]=>
    string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
    [113]=>
    int(1)
    [10004]=>
    string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
    [10006]=>
    string(32) ""
    [10018]=>
    string(90) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
    [10082]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-6a38af9410721abf3002d46cbb04cf76.txt"
    [10031]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-6a38af9410721abf3002d46cbb04cf76.txt"
  }
  ["cookie_file":protected]=>
  string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-6a38af9410721abf3002d46cbb04cf76.txt"
}
object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signe
d-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
    string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    ["Accept-Charset"]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
    ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["Keep-Alive"]=>
    string(3) "115"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(70) "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0)"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    [10102]=>
    string(0) ""
    [81]=>
    int(0)
    [64]=>
    int(0)
    [58]=>
    int(1)
    [78]=>
    int(10)
    [13]=>
    int(15)
    [10065]=>
    string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
    [10097]=>
    string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
    [113]=>
    int(1)
    [10004]=>
    string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
    [10006]=>
    string(32) ""
    [10018]=>
    string(70) "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0)"
    [10082]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-f972ff94b3dd45909c948e28ca1f75b2.txt"
    [10031]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-f972ff94b3dd45909c948e28ca1f75b2.txt"
  }
  ["cookie_file":protected]=>
  string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-f972ff94b3dd45909c948e28ca1f75b2.txt"
}
object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signe
d-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
    string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    ["Accept-Charset"]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
    ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["Keep-Alive"]=>
    string(3) "115"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(65) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    [10102]=>
    string(0) ""
    [81]=>
    int(0)
    [64]=>
    int(0)
    [58]=>
    int(1)
    [78]=>
    int(10)
    [13]=>
    int(15)
    [10065]=>
    string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
    [10097]=>
    string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
    [113]=>
    int(1)
    [10004]=>
    string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
    [10006]=>
    string(32) ""
    [10018]=>
    string(65) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
    [10082]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-80e3021c92debe638f494be1db37cdf5.txt"
    [10031]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-80e3021c92debe638f494be1db37cdf5.txt"
  }
  ["cookie_file":protected]=>
  string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-80e3021c92debe638f494be1db37cdf5.txt"
}
object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signe
d-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
    string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    ["Accept-Charset"]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
    ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["Keep-Alive"]=>
    string(3) "115"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/
537.36"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    [10102]=>
    string(0) ""
    [81]=>
    int(0)
    [64]=>
    int(0)
    [58]=>
    int(1)
    [78]=>
    int(10)
    [13]=>
    int(15)
    [10065]=>
    string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
    [10097]=>
    string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
    [113]=>
    int(1)
    [10004]=>
    string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
    [10006]=>
    string(32) ""
    [10018]=>
    string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/
537.36"
    [10082]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-e2fc30330ea96d286d0854838bcf18ea.txt"
    [10031]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-e2fc30330ea96d286d0854838bcf18ea.txt"
  }
  ["cookie_file":protected]=>
  string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-e2fc30330ea96d286d0854838bcf18ea.txt"
}
object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signe
d-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
    ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
    string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    ["Accept-Charset"]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ["Accept-Language"]=>
    string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
    ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["Keep-Alive"]=>
    string(3) "115"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    [10102]=>
    string(0) ""
    [81]=>
    int(0)
    [64]=>
    int(0)
    [58]=>
    int(1)
    [78]=>
    int(10)
    [13]=>
    int(15)
    [10065]=>
    string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
    [10097]=>
    string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
    [113]=>
    int(1)
    [10004]=>
    string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
    [10006]=>
    string(32) ""
    [10018]=>
    string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    [10082]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    [10031]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
  ["cookie_file":protected]=>
  string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
}
```

below is the results of var_dump($bparr);

```
browser array
array(5) {
  ["hosting terbaik"]=>
  object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/sig
ned-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Charset"]=>
      string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Keep-Alive"]=>
      string(3) "115"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    array(14) {
      [10102]=>
      string(0) ""
      [81]=>
      int(0)
      [64]=>
      int(0)
      [58]=>
      int(1)
      [78]=>
      int(10)
      [13]=>
      int(15)
      [10065]=>
      string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
      [10097]=>
      string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
      [113]=>
      int(1)
      [10004]=>
      string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
      [10006]=>
      string(32) ""
      [10018]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
      [10082]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
      [10031]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    }
    ["cookie_file":protected]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
  ["hosting indonesia"]=>
  object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/sig
ned-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Charset"]=>
      string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Keep-Alive"]=>
      string(3) "115"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    array(14) {
      [10102]=>
      string(0) ""
      [81]=>
      int(0)
      [64]=>
      int(0)
      [58]=>
      int(1)
      [78]=>
      int(10)
      [13]=>
      int(15)
      [10065]=>
      string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
      [10097]=>
      string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
      [113]=>
      int(1)
      [10004]=>
      string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
      [10006]=>
      string(32) ""
      [10018]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
      [10082]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
      [10031]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    }
    ["cookie_file":protected]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
  ["vps indonesia"]=>
  object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/sig
ned-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Charset"]=>
      string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Keep-Alive"]=>
      string(3) "115"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    array(14) {
      [10102]=>
      string(0) ""
      [81]=>
      int(0)
      [64]=>
      int(0)
      [58]=>
      int(1)
      [78]=>
      int(10)
      [13]=>
      int(15)
      [10065]=>
      string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
      [10097]=>
      string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
      [113]=>
      int(1)
      [10004]=>
      string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
      [10006]=>
      string(32) ""
      [10018]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
      [10082]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
      [10031]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    }
    ["cookie_file":protected]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
  ["vps murah"]=>
  object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/sig
ned-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Charset"]=>
      string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Keep-Alive"]=>
      string(3) "115"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    array(14) {
      [10102]=>
      string(0) ""
      [81]=>
      int(0)
      [64]=>
      int(0)
      [58]=>
      int(1)
      [78]=>
      int(10)
      [13]=>
      int(15)
      [10065]=>
      string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
      [10097]=>
      string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
      [113]=>
      int(1)
      [10004]=>
      string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
      [10006]=>
      string(32) ""
      [10018]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
      [10082]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
      [10031]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    }
    ["cookie_file":protected]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
  ["hosting cloud"]=>
  object(SerpScraper\Browser)#2 (3) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/sig
ned-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Charset"]=>
      string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(26) "en-US,en;q=0.9;q=0.8;q=0.7"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Keep-Alive"]=>
      string(3) "115"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    array(14) {
      [10102]=>
      string(0) ""
      [81]=>
      int(0)
      [64]=>
      int(0)
      [58]=>
      int(1)
      [78]=>
      int(10)
      [13]=>
      int(15)
      [10065]=>
      string(27) "D:\htdocs\cacert\cacert.pem"
      [10097]=>
      string(16) "D:\htdocs\cacert"
      [113]=>
      int(1)
      [10004]=>
      string(19) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5050"
      [10006]=>
      string(32) ""
      [10018]=>
      string(151) "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36"
      [10082]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
      [10031]=>
      string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
    }
    ["cookie_file":protected]=>
    string(62) "D:\htdocs\cookiefiles\gtc-81e37ba09eba2972fc4e695781b0f461.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: What `$google->getBrowser();` do? Are you sure it return the same result each call inside one loop iteration?

Comment: If I got your idea right - change `$bparr[$keyword] = $google->getBrowser();` to `$bparr[$keyword][] = $google->getBrowser();` and it will work.

Comment: i had showing the var_dump results from $google->getBrowser()

compare the results with $bparr var_dump results

Comment: I had try your suggestion but the results is still same for $bparr var_dump, it's still showing the last values from $google->getBrowser()

Comment: try `$bparr[$keyword][] = clone $google->getBrowser();`

Comment: yep already trying that one but still got same results
i'm almost crazy because of this thing

Comment: Give a link to a code of `SerpScraper\Browser`, is it opensourced?

Comment: also, show `var_dump($keywords)` please

Comment: yes, it's open source can be downloaded from https://github.com/Athlon1600/SerpScraper

i just happened want to make it multi threaded using curl

var_dump($keywords) is list of keywords that i want to use for scraping

Comment: @krylov123 using clone is work, may i know what is clone function related with this ?

Comment: I assumed that myabe `Browser` object is Singleton and `clone` is one way to workaround this. But, I've checked github sources - these Classes (and parents of it) are not Singleton at all. So it means that usual `array_push( $bparr[$keyword], $google->getBrowser() );` will work.

Comment: I had trying array_push and it not work, only clone worked

Comment: Check my explanation in the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looked at `Browser` class source code [here](https://github.com/Athlon1600/SerpScraper/blob/master/src/Engine/SearchEngine.php), you will find that `getBrowser()` method didn't return new instance of `Class`, but instead it return reference to it's own property, which contain another `Object`:

```php
public function getBrowser()
{
    return $this->browser;
}
```

Because of that, each time you add `$google->getBrowser()` to the array, you actually add reference to the same object. So you have many references to the same `Object` here.

When you call `var_dump` at the end of a script - it shows you many outputs of the same object (which are the same, obviously).

Take a look at official [Objects and references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) article to better understand how references works.

**Solution:**

To workaround your situation you can just clone the `Object` each time you need to save it to the array by using `clone`:

```php
$bparr[$keyword][] = clone $google->getBrowser();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply :)
I had successful making multi proxy checker using multi curl and right now just need to figure out how to send to 2captcha to solving captcha error for each response and adding new proxies to replace not working proxies when visiting google since there will be several response in the middle google visit

in some case google not even giving data-s key and i need to replace the proxy that not giving data-s key response